# Webpage that shows cookies

Tags: php, cookies, passwords, html

I want to write a webpage that shows cookies from other sides. 
I think PHP is the best bet. So how do i call a a cookie value from a website like Facebook or something? My knowlege if PHP is very basic. When i look at Facebook cookies they are called like datr or xs and the value is like kWXgUQBMYHc1oFyEGWA2vUae

Comment: You can't do that. You are not allowed to see cookies from other domains. Security restrictions. And I'm am glad you can't...

Comment: Cookies are generally issued to the browser specific to the domain from where it's issued. The browser won't send cookies to other domains, because that would be a security vulnerability. Pretty much everyone works to make sure cookies can't be read cross domain, so that's not something that could be done easily.

Comment: Yikes! You can't do this for very good reasons. Imagine if a website could peek at your browsing history... people wouldn't use the internet if this was possible. In fact, if you could grab cookies, you could also steal visitors' internet accounts, too. So, no, not possible.

Comment: (There was an interesting vulnerability in Firefox that could allow a site to determine whether or not you'd visited a particular site, using the visited link colour. With the speed of JavaScript now, spending even several minutes on a rogue site would allow it to check tens of thousands of domains! Hole long since plugged, I believe.)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't look at cookie values from other websites due to security restrictions. You can get a lot of private data from cookies, you know! I'd try another project, if I were you :)

Comment: Fortunately, you mean `;-)`.

Comment: Hahaha, fortunately for the web at large, unfortunately for the OP!